# Beautiful Soup and <script> tag - Function data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a python script to look at web scrapping. I can extract most the text I need within div or class but am having an issue with  tag.

```
url1 = "https://www.wowhead.com/"
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1, "html.parser")
test = soup1.find_all('div', attrs={"featured-content-block type-today-in-wow today-in-wow"})[0].find_all('script')[-1]
```

this returns:
<script>new WH.News.TodayInWoW(**[{"assaults":{"duration":302400,"expansion":8,...."zone":10288}}}]**);</script>

What I need is in the *WH.News.TodayInWoW* function (not sure what part of script to call it, emboldened) but I don't know how to extract this. Either a list or dictionary, I plan to filter out the keys/values I want.

Anything would be appreciated, I have already looked at a few other BS and email extraction but doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the substring (notice the `[31: -11]` at the end):

```
test = soup1.find_all('div', attrs={"featured-content-block type-today-in-wow today-in-wow"})[0].find_all('script')[-1][31: -11]
```

To get the actual dictionary, eval the string:

```
d = eval(test)
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried that already, had to use .find_all('script')[-1].string[31: -11] to get it as text but not sure about converting that to dictionary etc as eval(test) fails

Comment: @Fiery-Skyline To me, eval works. What error are you getting with eval?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly you cannot web-scrape a function. What you are doing is just web scraping the parameters of the function. Assuming even if the website has made the script public, you'd need to go to inspect element > sources > script and then try to find the js file where that function is!

Comment: If I understood him correctly, he wants to get the *parameter* which was passed to that function

Comment: Yes, the data I want loads and is visible to me but I just cannot get it into a usable format. The parameters look like a list of dictionaries but im unsure how to access them within the new WH.News.TodayInWoW() method

Answer (score 0):

You could use BeautifulSoup to extract as you did, then you would need to do some string/data manipulation and the `json` package to read that into python as a list and dictionary. Or simply, what I did was use regex to extract the json from the html request. Not sure what you are after exactly, but I converted that into a table with `pandas` to show you the output.

```
import requests
import re
import json

url1 = "https://www.wowhead.com/"

pattern = 'WH.News.TodayInWoW\((\[.*\])'

html1 = requests.get(url1).text
jsonStr = re.search(pattern, html1).group(1)
jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

**Output:**

```
print(jsonData)
[{'assaults': [{'duration': 302400, 'expansion': 8, 'iconActive': 'ui_sigil_kyrian', 'iconInactive': 'item_rep_deathsadvance_01', 'id': 'covenant-assault', 'label': 'Covenant Assault', 'name': 'Kyrian Assault', 'requiresExpansion': False, 'type': 'covenant-assault', 'upcoming': [1644634800, 1644937200, 1645239600, 1645542000, 1645844400], 'url': '/guides/covenant-assaults-maw-invasions'}, {'duration': 21600, 'expansion': 6, 'iconActive': 'inv_misc_map08', 'iconInactive': 'achievement_faction_legionfall', 'id': 'legion-assaults', 'label': 'Legion Assaults', 'name': None, 'requiresExpansion': True, 'type': 'legion-assaults', 'upcoming': [1644984000, 1645050600, 1645117200, 1645183800, 1645250400], 'url': '/legion-assaults-guide'}, {'duration': 25200, 'expansion': 7, 'iconActive': 'inv_misc_map08', 'iconInactive': 'inv_misc_map08', 'id': 'faction-assaults', 'label': 'Faction Assaults', 'name': None, 'requiresExpansion': True, 'type': 'faction-assaults', 'upcoming': [1644955200, 1645023600, 1645092000, 1645160400, 1645228800], 'url': '/guides/battle-for-azeroth-incursions'}, {'duration': 604800, 'expansion': 7, 'iconActive': 'achievement_zone_uldum', 'iconInactive': 'inv_eyeofnzothpet', 'id': 'nzoth-assaults-major', 'label': "N'Zoth Assaults - Major", 'name': 'Uldum', 'requiresExpansion': True, 'type': 'nzoth-assaults-major', 'upcoming': [1644332400, 1644937200, 1645542000, 1646146800, 1646751600], 'url': '/guides/visions-of-nzoth-assaults'}, {'duration': 302400, 'expansion': 7, 'iconActive': 'achievement_zone_valeofeternalblossoms', 'iconInactive': 'inv_eyeofnzothpet', 'id': 'nzoth-assaults-minor', 'label': "N'Zoth Assaults - Minor", 'name': 'Vale of Eternal Blossoms', 'requiresExpansion': True, 'type': 'nzoth-assaults-minor', 'upcoming': [1644634800, 1644937200, 1645239600, 1645542000, 1645844400], 'url': '/guides/visions-of-nzoth-assaults'}], 'id': 'US', 'name': 'NA', 'progression': {'defeatedBosses': 10, 'icon': 'achievement_raid_torghastraid', 'id': 'progression', 'name': 'Sanctum of Domination', 'topGuildCount': 1683, 'totalBosses': 10, 'type': 'progression', 'url': 'https://www.wowhead.com/guides/sanctum-of-domination-raid-overview-strategy-boss-guides-rewards'}, 'warfronts': {'9734': {'expansion': 7, 'contributions': None, 'icon': 'achievement_zone_arathihighlands_01', 'name': 'Arathi Highlands', 'progress': 17.5049603, 'requiresExpansion': True, 'side': 2, 'stateId': 'attacking', 'stateName': 'Horde Attacking', 'url': '/how-to-win-battle-for-stromgarde-warfront-strategy-guide', 'zone': 9734}, '10288': {'expansion': 7, 'contributions': None, 'icon': 'achievement_zone_darkshore_01', 'name': 'Darkshore', 'progress': 86.73307299613953, 'requiresExpansion': True, 'side': 1, 'stateId': 'contributing', 'stateName': 'Alliance Contributing', 'url': '/guides/launching-a-warfront-through-contributions', 'zone': 10288}}}, {'assaults': [{'duration': 302400, 'expansion': 8, 'iconActive': 'ui_sigil_kyrian', 'iconInactive': 'item_rep_deathsadvance_01', 'id': 'covenant-assault', 'label': 'Covenant Assault', 'name': 'Kyrian Assault', 'requiresExpansion': False, 'type': 'covenant-assault', 'upcoming': [1644692400, 1644994800, 1645297200, 1645599600, 1645902000], 'url': '/guides/covenant-assaults-maw-invasions'}, {'duration': 21600, 'expansion': 6, 'iconActive': 'inv_misc_map08', 'iconInactive': 'achievement_faction_legionfall', 'id': 'legion-assaults', 'label': 'Legion Assaults', 'name': None, 'requiresExpansion': True, 'type': 'legion-assaults', 'upcoming': [1644955200, 1645021800, 1645088400, 1645155000, 1645221600], 'url': '/legion-assaults-guide'}, {'duration': 25200, 'expansion': 7, 'iconActive': 'inv_tiragardesound', 'iconInactive': 'inv_misc_map08', 'id': 'faction-assaults', 'label': 'Faction Assaults', 'name': 'Tiragarde Sound', 'requiresExpansion': True, 'type': 'faction-assaults', 'upcoming': [1644922800, 1644991200, 1645059600, 1645128000, 1645196400], 'url': '/guides/battle-for-azeroth-incursions'}, {'duration': 604800, 'expansion': 7, 'iconActive': 'achievement_zone_uldum', 'iconInactive': 'inv_eyeofnzothpet', 'id': 'nzoth-assaults-major', 'label': "N'Zoth Assaults - Major", 'name': 'Uldum', 'requiresExpansion': True, 'type': 'nzoth-assaults-major', 'upcoming': [1644390000, 1644994800, 1645599600, 1646204400, 1646809200], 'url': '/guides/visions-of-nzoth-assaults'}, {'duration': 302400, 'expansion': 7, 'iconActive': 'achievement_zone_valeofeternalblossoms', 'iconInactive': 'inv_eyeofnzothpet', 'id': 'nzoth-assaults-minor', 'label': "N'Zoth Assaults - Minor", 'name': 'Vale of Eternal Blossoms', 'requiresExpansion': True, 'type': 'nzoth-assaults-minor', 'upcoming': [1644692400, 1644994800, 1645297200, 1645599600, 1645902000], 'url': '/guides/visions-of-nzoth-assaults'}], 'id': 'EU', 'name': 'EU', 'progression': {'defeatedBosses': 10, 'icon': 'achievement_raid_torghastraid', 'id': 'progression', 'name': 'Sanctum of Domination', 'topGuildCount': 1683, 'totalBosses': 10, 'type': 'progression', 'url': 'https://www.wowhead.com/guides/sanctum-of-domination-raid-overview-strategy-boss-guides-rewards'}, 'warfronts': {'9734': {'expansion': 7, 'contributions': None, 'icon': 'achievement_zone_arathihighlands_01', 'name': 'Arathi Highlands', 'progress': 0.9389017708599567, 'requiresExpansion': True, 'side': 2, 'stateId': 'contributing', 'stateName': 'Horde Contributing', 'url': '/guides/launching-a-warfront-through-contributions', 'zone': 9734}, '10288': {'expansion': 7, 'contributions': None, 'icon': 'achievement_zone_darkshore_01', 'name': 'Darkshore', 'progress': 49.4943783, 'requiresExpansion': True, 'side': 2, 'stateId': 'attacking', 'stateName': 'Horde Attacking', 'url': '/guides/rewards-from-the-darkshore-warfront', 'zone': 10288}}}]
```

**Into Dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData, record_path=['assaults'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
   duration  expansion                              iconActive                    iconInactive                    id                    label                      name  requiresExpansion                  type                                                      upcoming                                      url
0    302400          8                         ui_sigil_kyrian       item_rep_deathsadvance_01      covenant-assault         Covenant Assault            Kyrian Assault              False      covenant-assault  [1644634800, 1644937200, 1645239600, 1645542000, 1645844400]  /guides/covenant-assaults-maw-invasions
1     21600          6                          inv_misc_map08  achievement_faction_legionfall       legion-assaults          Legion Assaults                      None               True       legion-assaults  [1644984000, 1645050600, 1645117200, 1645183800, 1645250400]                   /legion-assaults-guide
2     25200          7                          inv_misc_map08                  inv_misc_map08      faction-assaults         Faction Assaults                      None               True      faction-assaults  [1644955200, 1645023600, 1645092000, 1645160400, 1645228800]    /guides/battle-for-azeroth-incursions
3    604800          7                  achievement_zone_uldum               inv_eyeofnzothpet  nzoth-assaults-major  N'Zoth Assaults - Major                     Uldum               True  nzoth-assaults-major  [1644332400, 1644937200, 1645542000, 1646146800, 1646751600]        /guides/visions-of-nzoth-assaults
4    302400          7  achievement_zone_valeofeternalblossoms               inv_eyeofnzothpet  nzoth-assaults-minor  N'Zoth Assaults - Minor  Vale of Eternal Blossoms               True  nzoth-assaults-minor  [1644634800, 1644937200, 1645239600, 1645542000, 1645844400]        /guides/visions-of-nzoth-assaults
5    302400          8                         ui_sigil_kyrian       item_rep_deathsadvance_01      covenant-assault         Covenant Assault            Kyrian Assault              False      covenant-assault  [1644692400, 1644994800, 1645297200, 1645599600, 1645902000]  /guides/covenant-assaults-maw-invasions
6     21600          6                          inv_misc_map08  achievement_faction_legionfall       legion-assaults          Legion Assaults                      None               True       legion-assaults  [1644955200, 1645021800, 1645088400, 1645155000, 1645221600]                   /legion-assaults-guide
7     25200          7                      inv_tiragardesound                  inv_misc_map08      faction-assaults         Faction Assaults           Tiragarde Sound               True      faction-assaults  [1644922800, 1644991200, 1645059600, 1645128000, 1645196400]    /guides/battle-for-azeroth-incursions
8    604800          7                  achievement_zone_uldum               inv_eyeofnzothpet  nzoth-assaults-major  N'Zoth Assaults - Major                     Uldum               True  nzoth-assaults-major  [1644390000, 1644994800, 1645599600, 1646204400, 1646809200]        /guides/visions-of-nzoth-assaults
9    302400          7  achievement_zone_valeofeternalblossoms               inv_eyeofnzothpet  nzoth-assaults-minor  N'Zoth Assaults - Minor  Vale of Eternal Blossoms               True  nzoth-assaults-minor  [1644692400, 1644994800, 1645297200, 1645599600, 1645902000]        /guides/visions-of-nzoth-assaults
```